# How to add a log file to wwwroot folder using XML's <target fileName=""/>

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, nlog

I am trying to add a log folder with log files to my project's wwwroot folder using Nlog.Config. The code is in XML and I have no knowledge of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<!-- the targets to write to -->
<targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target name="allfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="\DemoLogs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"/> <!-- fileName needs a change -->
</targets>

<!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
<rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
</rules>
```

Comment: Have you tried [${aspnet-appbasepath}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-AppBasePath-layout-renderer). Ex. `fileName="${aspnet-appbasepath}\DemoLogs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"`. See also: https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers

Comment: I tried just now, but I don't see any new folder in the project itself nor in the wwwroot.

Comment: I even tried ${aspnet-webrootpath} but this also does not work.

Comment: Guess you have to activate NLog InternalLogger and investigate the result of the different file-paths. And whether your application have write-permissions to the file-paths. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I used the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193178/rolf-kristensen) sent by user: [Rolf Kristensen](https://%20nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers) and I found that `${aspnet-webrootpath}\yourPath` will do the job. I change the code, see changes below.

### Changes:

- Changed `fileName="\DemoLogs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"` to
  `fileName="${aspnet-webrootpath}\DemoLogs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"`
  to make a new link.
- Added `throwConfigExceptions="true"` to the  as such `<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" throwConfigExceptions="true">` for debugging.

## Errors:

As I run the program it gave me 3 inner errors:

- NLogConfigurationException: 'FileTarget' cannot assign property 'FileName'='${aspnet-webrootpath}\DemoLogs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log'. Error: Failed to parse layout containing type: aspnet-webrootpath
- NLogConfigurationException: Failed to parse layout containing type: aspnet-webrootpath
- ArgumentException: LayoutRenderer type-alias is unknown: 'aspnet-webrootpath'. Extension NLog.Web.AspNetCore not included?

## Solution

To fix those errors I used [HitHub's solution](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/264) and added this to the code:

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>
```

## Finall Code:

The code below works 100%, tried it, saved a log file in the `wwwroot` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  throwConfigExceptions="true">
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>

<!-- the targets to write to -->
<targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target name="allfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${aspnet-webrootpath}\DemoLogs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"/>
</targets>

<!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
<rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
</rules>
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-6